# Linux or Windows Web Hosting and others

Tags: html, css, hosting

So I'm new to the web hosting thing. My website is made with HTML and CSS. It's going to go online soon but I'm stuck at two things.

Firstly, I'm using arvixe.com for hosting. I came across Linux and Windows based web hosting. What are the differences and which one should I choose?

Secondly, my website has this section that is the same across multiple pages so I got this general file with the code called "header.html". How do I put this across multiple pages?

 Please help guys. Thank you

Comment: Here's an article that you should read: http://www.lunarpages.com/uptime/linux-vs-windows-web-hosting-how-choose-right-server-os

Comment: The main difference is Windows support both ASP.NET and PHP while Linux only support PHP. The other differences, you can find it on google. If you only host HTML and CSS site, you can always host your site on linux platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main Difference Between Linux and Windows is Hosting si its usually its server side language and its cost. Usually windows is more expensive than linux hosting because the Windows Server license is not free.

Windows also used ASP.NET technology and LINUX is using PHP. so, it all depends about your necessity. If you use PHP use Linux, if you ASP.NET you use Windows. But judging by your header.html, it seems you doesn't use either PHP or ASP.NET. In that case either Windows or Linux doesn't have any difference.

Regarding including header.html, you have several options, it all depends what language you are using.

1. [Include File in ASP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306575)
2. [Include file in PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)
3. [Include file in jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp)

Since you doesn't use PHP or ASP, I guess you need to use option number 3. Good Luck.

Edit :
To use jQuery you need to include it first, refer to [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp). And then you need to use this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#somediv").load('somefile.html');
});
```

change 'somediv' and 'somefile' according to your needs.

Comment: What do I need to change for PHP?

Comment: So if I use jQuery. What changes do I need to make to the page??

Comment: What do I put in the somediv? Sorry
For example, my file is under test.html and it's inside my div with id "main"
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#main").load('test.html');
});